# Is it possible to retrieve the Status Bar Icon from an application?

Tags: android

I'm able to access the icon of an application providing its package name and using `PackageManager.getApplicationIcon()`, but I haven't been able to find a method in the documentation for the status bar icon (the small icon that appears when there is a notification).

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get notification title and text and notification.
From `StatusBarNotification` you can get notification by `statusBarNotification.getNotification()` and get icon by https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#getSmallIcon()

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {


    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
    String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    String title = extras.getString("android.title");
    String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();

    Log.i("Package",pack);
    Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
    Log.i("Title",title);
    Log.i("Text",text);

    Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
    msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
    msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
    msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
    msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);


}
```

You can get more info @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Note: This method is only available on API 18.

Further investigation I've found an example made by another user on how to use NotificationListenerService:

https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example

AccessibilityService is to handle accessibility touches:

> An accessibility service runs in the background and receives callbacks
>   by the system when AccessibilityEvents are fired. Such events denote
>   some state transition in the user interface, for example, the focus
>   has changed, a button has been clicked, etc. Such a service can
>   optionally request the capability for querying the content of the
>   active window. Development of an accessibility service requires
>   extending this class and implementing its abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

Since every app can set the notification icon at runtime you cannot get it. It could even be different for every notification by the same app.

Comment: Oh, understood, yeah, I didn't think about it.

Thanks!

Comment: But maybe is possible to access it from the Notification itself? I know I can access there the packagename, the title, the text...